# How to convert index column of int64 type to hour in matplotlib xticks

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I want to plot `matplotlib` bar graph with data:

```
     value
Hour    
0    100
1    200
2    100
3    200
4    100
5    200
6    200
7    200
8    100
9    200
10   100
11   100
12   200
13   100
14   100
15   200
16   100
17   200
18   100
19   100
20   100
21   200
22   100
23   200
```

which returned graph with integers `1 to 23` as `xticks`. Expected output is to have the `xticks` changed to time format, i.e. `hour:minute`, such as `01:00`, `02:00`, etc... `Hour` was  in `int64` type.

Code for graph:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,  24), fontsize=30)  
plt.bar(x.index, x.value, color = 'c') 

# x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index, format='%H').strftime('%H')

# ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

# x.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in x.index]

ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

plt.xlabel('Hour', fontsize=35)
plt.ylabel('Value', fontsize=35)
```

I tried to convert index column `Hour` into Time(hour) format with:

```
x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index, format='%H').strftime('%H')
```

which caught error:

```
TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (object) and width (float64) are incompatible
```

Also tried `ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))`
and `x.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in x.index]` based on  other similar questions but none worked.

Why isn't it working? Is it because of the index form or I didn't change the `Hour` column from `int64` to `time` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Use [`pd.Index.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.astype.html)

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index.astype('object'),format='%H').strftime('%H:%M')

Index(['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00',
       '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00',
       '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
      dtype='object', name='Hour')
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Could you please elaborate why `pd.Index.astype` worked but not `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: I realise that I made a silly mistake. It seems `pd.to_datetime` would work, if I had placed it at the beginning of the code. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @nilsinelabore Yes, `pd.to_datetime` should work with `int`, `float`, `str`. I was wondering why it didn't work with `int`